# Externalize my own web applications

Tags: html, iframe, iframe-app

I created some web "applications", in a nutshell they are forms that call my server (ajax/php) and get back responses (without refresh).
Now I want to allow other website developers to use my app on their site. Some thing like: "Copy and paste this code on your body to show this app on your site".
Are iframe the answer? Can someone point me to the right direction,
Thanks

EDIT

I found jquery .load()

```
$('#test').load('http://mysiteurl.com #myAppID')

<div id="test"></div>
```

console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mysiteurl.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I Try also with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7MaXx/ but it load all the page, not the specific #myAppID

Comment: `<div id="something" src="something.html">` I something like this on the web. Maybe you can look into that? Google keyword: div instead of iframe

Comment: Mmh interesting...I see for ex that Google+ Badges for page (that are almost the same thingh I want to obtain) use a combination of empty <div> and <script> tag with pure javascript in it...tomorrow I'll take a better look.